# Application Error message when browsing Azure deployed web app

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I created a simple web app (serverless) and deployed the web app using Azure App Service VS Code extension. I chose Linux + Node LTS environment. I configured deployment source to a local Git repo (also tried remote GitHub repo) and deployed. The deployment shows successful message. But when I browse the site, it throws a message (after 3-4 mins) that there was an ":( Application error". The admin diagnostics link doesn't show any error. Any reason why this could be happening?
Where can I find error details?
The web app compiles/runs fine on the local host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable Log Streamming, then you'll be able to figure out what the problem is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs

As another option, you can also instrument your application with Application Insights:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs

Comment: Thanks. When I stream logs, I see a message "did not start within expected time limit." and to see "container logs for debugging". Where can I see that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks. It leads to just this message and nothing more. "An unknown error has occurred. Check the diagnostic log for details." This is so complex. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're welcome. In case it answers your question, mark as a reply

Answer (score 2):

On Azure WebApps, the container/application must respond to HTTP pings on the required port (check docker run command in the Log Stream) within 230 seconds, by default.

For a NodeJS app, you'd need to start the server in the following way:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);
```

Try deploying the sample available here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world

If that does not help, enable App Service Logs and check for any errors in the Log Stream.

I had created a NodeJS app which integrates with Application Insights some days back:
https://github.com/gkgaurav31/nodejs-application-insights-test-app

Answer (score 1):

change your listen port either 8080 or 1337

Answer (score 1):

By default, NodeJS webapp runs on port 8080. You are either running your port on some other port (Ex: 3000 or so) and then deploying it to webapp. Try changing your port in NodeJS app to 8080 and it should work.