# Unable to deploy Docker Image as Azure App Service using Azure DevOps Build and Release Pipeline

Tags: docker

I am unable to deploy an image as Azure App Service using Azure DevOps Build and Release pipeline.
But its working fine when I am deploying it from Visual Studio Code.
The error I see after deploying using Azure DevOps pipeline is :

:( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

The way I have configured the pipeline is :

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: buildAndPush
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: Docker1
    repository: goyalsneh2/dbchange22
    Dockerfile: Dockerfile

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: DockerImagePOC22'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Enterprise (###)'
    appType: webAppContainer
    WebAppName: DockerImagePOC22
    DockerNamespace: goyalsneh2/dbchange22
    DockerRepository: 'goyalsneh2/dbchange22:19'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039716/application-error-message-when-browsing-azure-deployed-web-app